# How to order a dict by its keys and print it line by line?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have this code:

```py
def __init__(self, username, password):
        self.likesposts = {}

code to fill self.likesposts

top = "{" + "\n".join("{!r}: {!r},".format(k, v) for k, v in self.likesposts.items()) + "}"
top = sorted(top)
print(top)
```

But it's not working.

A line in `self.likesposts` looks like this:

```
{'11,821': 'https://www.example.com', '2,449': 'https://www.example.com', '26,153': 'https://www.example.com'}
```

How could I go about ordering this dict by its keys, but at the same time print one `key-value pair' per line?

Thank you in advance.

EDIT:

```
for key, val in sorted(self.likesposts.items()):
    print(f'{key}: {val}')
```

This prints it line by line, but it's still not sorted

EDIT 2:
Expected output:

```
{
'26,153': 'https://www.example.com'
'11,821': 'https://www.example.com',
'2,449': 'https://www.example.com',
}
```

Comment: You create a string that looks like a dictionary and then sort the characters in that string. What did you expect? Use a proper dict comprehension, i.e. with `{` and `}` not `"{"` and `"}"`. Also, `sorted(top)` will just be a list of sorted keys. Use another dict comprehension to recreate the sorted dict from that.

Comment: Dictionaries are unordered by definition. You can NOT sort them. However, Python has a `collections` module with a special OrderedDict type that you may want to use: https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/collections.html

Comment: @Ronald `OrderedDict` gives insertion order, not sorted order.  And it's obsolete in newer versions of Python anyway, regular dictionaries work the same way.

Comment: Regarding your edit, that would work if the keys were integers instead of strings.  Strings don't sort numerically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create a new dictionary:

```
d_original = {'2,449': 1, '11,821': 2, '26,153': 3}
sorted_items = sorted(d_original.items(), key=lambda item: int(item[0].replace(',', '')), reverse=True)
# from collections import OrderedDict
# d_new = OrderedDict(sorted_items)
d_new = dict(sorted_items)
for k,v in d_new.items():
    print(f'{k}: {v}')
```

Prints:

```
26,153: 3
11,821: 2
2,449: 1
```

**Update**

Or in your case:

```
sorted_items = sorted(self.likeposts.items(), key=lambda item: int(item[0].replace(',', '')), reverse=True)
self.likeposts = dict(sorted_items)
for k,v in slef.likeposts.items():
    print(f'{k}: {v}')
```

Since Python 3.6 regular `dict` objects maintain insertion order. If your are using Python 2 or Python < 3.6, then use a `collections.OrderedDict` rather than a `dict`.

Comment: Thank you, but this doesnt order the keys. Please look at my expected output

Comment: In what way does this not order the keys? You end up with an identical dictionary whose keys are in sorted ascending order. Apply this algorithm to *your* dictionary; this is just an example dictionary. Substitute `self.likeposts` for wherever you see `d_original` and `d_new`.

Comment: I see you want it in descending order, so look at my edit.

Comment: '3,374: someurl'  this should be between the first and second. It's not being ordered properly

Comment: Ah, it needs to do a numerical sort after getting rid of commas. See update. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

Dictionaries in Python are unordered. If you want to access by sorted keys you could do something like this:

```
d = {"a": 4, "c": 10, "b": 11, "d" : 6}  

for key in sorted(d.keys()): 
    print(f'{key} {d[key]}')
```

EDIT:

You can't edit the dictionary while you iterate over it. So store the values sorted in a new dictionary, and overwrite the existing.

```
tmp = {}
for key in sorted(d.keys(), key=lambda x: int(x.replace(",",""))): 
    tmp[key] = d[key] 
    print(f'{key} {d[key]}') 
self.likeposts = tmp
```